# LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose not working?

Tags: linux, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm trying to track down a problem with direct rendering being disabled, after reverting to nouveau on Fedora 18 x64 (the official NVidia drivers were having stability issues). Unfortunately, when glxinfo says, "If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose", it seems to be lying, and I need to figure out why.

I've tried about every permutation, from `export LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose && glxinfo` to `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo` and just about everything in between; "verbose" in quotes, 1 instead of "verbose", running as root or not... absolutely no difference.

A couple other people seem to have had this problem in the past, but never got a resolution. Here's hoping we can change that.

Comment: I have same problem with glxinfo compiled for 32 bit machine in Fedore 19. Have you find source of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo > /dev/null
```

The debug output goes to `stderr` so I have redirected `stdout` to null so that it doesn't clutter up the debugging output and make it unreadable.  It only outputs six lines of debug info for me, which would easily get lost in the normal output.

I am using the Intel drivers that are part of Mesa, running under Arch Linux.